# what is the best way to deploy react app in lan only

Tags: reactjs, lan

what is the best way to deploy a react web app (ex. employee database) on the local area network only? i'm using create-react-app and i'm almost done with the code but after that, i don't know what to do. it was easier to do this in php/mysql with the help of xammp. but i would like to do this using react this time. thank you

Comment: Do you have a backend server like Express? I assume so since DB is involved in your question.

Comment: @devserkan No, i don't have. im just using mysql and knex js from the npm which allows me to make changes in the db.

Comment: So, no backend at all? If so, you can serve your app statically.

Comment: @devserkan. im actually looking for the best way. i dont think that will be a good idea to npm install the app in each pc on the office. but im considering learning express if that is the best way.

Comment: No need to install app to each pc. You can serve the app via a web server statically, I meant that. After building your app you can serve it with the server you prefer. Apache, Nginx, etc. If there is a backend, after merging your project something like Express there are other steps to deploy. But for a simple static app, you can do it easily.

Comment: @devserkan can you guide me how to do that. im not really sure what you're talking about. im more of a frontend coder only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is totally static you can serve it with a web server after building. When you are done with your app first build it with:

```
yarn build
```

After this you will have all your static files in your build directory inside your project. build/static/js and build/static/css contains bundled js and css files. Those files are being attached to your index.html file. So, when you serve this directory with a web server like a regular html site, you can use your app.

Comment: really sorry for the very late reply. i just copied the files from the build to the html folder in our linux server. at first it was just blank but after some research i just had to add something in the package file. thank you very much for your help

Comment: what did you add in the package file to get it work?

Answer (score 3):

The react is already working in your local lan IP

for example your local lan ip is 192.168.1.20 you and your react running port is

localhost:3000

other PC's mobile devices laptop could already access the server in your PC via

http:/192.168.1.20:3000

just make sure you enable it to be allowed in your firewall usually the antivirus does not permit is so try to set enable in the firewall settings in your antivirus and windows firewall

Answer (score 0):

By default
type `npm run build`
after a build is successful then,
type `serve -s build`
it will give you URL
use that with IP to other devices connected in the same network.